# Taking DCT of an image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dct

I'm doing a watermarking project in MATLAB. I have applied blockwise DCT to image and watermark is embedded. Inverse DCT is taken and new watermarked image is stored. For extraction purpose, when I again tried to take the DCT i could find some change happened when compared to the DCT image just before doing inverse DCT(in watremarking process). Because of this change i couldnt extract correct watermark. Can anyone suggest some methods to avoid this changes?

Here is the code I have tried:

```
img=imread('cameraman.tif'); 
original=double(img)-128; 

fundct = @(block_struct) dct2(block_struct.data); 
dctimg=blockproc(original,[8 8],fundct); 

modified=dctimg+10;%modification is done 

funrev = @(block_struct) idct2(block_struct.data); %to perform inverse dct 
invdct = blockproc(modified,[8 8],funrev); % combining 8*8 blocks 

invdct=uint8(invdct)+128;% now invdct is modified image 
againdct=double(invdct)-128; % agin spply dct to it 

fundct = @(block_struct) dct2(block_struct.data); 
againdct=blockproc(againdct,[8 8],fundct);
```

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're saying.  Are you stating that you take the blockwise DCT, you modify the DCT coefficients, then take the inverse DCT.  Next when you take the DCT again, you notice a change?... well of course there are changes in comparison to the original.  You modified the coefficients so when you find the DCT of the modified image, it's going to be different from the original.  Can you be more specific with what you're doing? Can you show us any code? This question will inevitably close as it appears that you have shown no effort.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you people. Actually what i meant was like,let A be the image on which blockwise DCT is applied.After modification, let that image becomes B.Now i take the inverse DCT of B.let that be C.Again if i take DCT of C, it should be equivalent to B,right? But Iam not getting this result. I can realize the difference when compared with the original image. anyway sorry for confusing you. thanks for reply.hope you got the question now. I will attach a sample program to demonstrate the problem

Comment: I'll edit your post so that you have this code, but in the future you should avoid putting code that is more than 2 lines in a comments block... it just looks really awful.

Comment: img=imread('cameraman.tif');
original=double(img)-128;
fundct = @(block_struct) dct2(block_struct.data);
dctimg=blockproc(original,[8 8],fundct);
modified=dctimg+10;%modification is done
funrev = @(block_struct) idct2(block_struct.data); 
invdct = blockproc(modified,[8 8],funrev); 
invdct=uint8(invdct)+128;% now invdct is modified image
againdct=double(invdct)-128; % agin spply dct to it
fundct = @(block_struct) dct2(block_struct.data); 
againdct=blockproc(againdct,[8 8],fundct);

Comment: %'againdct' should be equivalent to 'modified'
%it is 95 % equivalent but (modified - againdct) is not equal to 0
%i need it to be 0
%because such a slight error creates errors in my result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is specifically at this point in your code:

```
invdct=uint8(invdct)+128;% now invdct is modified image 
againdct=double(invdct)-128; % agin spply dct to it
```

In your results, are they slightly inaccurate?  That's because of your `uint8` casting.   `invdct` will inevitably be floating point, and so if you cast the variable to `uint8`, any precision that is required to accurately reconstruct the DCT coefficients is removed.  For example, when you take the inverse DCT, you will get floating point values, like 25.6161 or 9.19391.  These values may not appear in your image, but these are the kinds of numbers you would get.

Doing `uint8`, will remove this precision, and so you would get `25` and `9`.  If you do the DCT of this, you will for sure not get the same results as you did with the other image.  You are essentially quantizing and thus your inaccuracy occurs.

As such, you should avoid casting to `uint8` if you want to reconstruct the same DCT results.  Try removing this cast and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much..I have been trying to solve this error for a long time.It's working. Thanks a lot. You pointed out the exact error. This will help my project a lot. Thank you so much. Also I will take your suggestion for entering code in comment space. Thanks for that too.

Comment: @JINIJOHN - No problem!  My pleasure :)  Yeah try to avoid putting huge lines of code in a comments block.  It doesn't look nice.  I'm glad I helped you find your problem, and good luck!

Comment: @ rayryeng I have applied the concept it my project.but it is not working may be bcz, i have used color images there. I have mailed the code to ur email id. Please help me in pointing out the error.Please